# Wordpress - How to login user to frontend programmatically

Tags: wordpress

I created function for loging in users on frontend using this example: https://gist.github.com/iandunn/8162246

After user logs in `is_user_logged_in()` function returns `true` only inside this function where I placed code for login part.

How do I login users globally?
This is my code:

```
function programmatic_login( $username ) {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        wp_logout();
    }
    add_filter( 'authenticate', 'allow_programmatic_login', 10, 3 );
    $user = wp_signon( array( 'user_login' => $username ) );
    remove_filter( 'authenticate', 'allow_programmatic_login', 10, 3 );
    if ( is_a( $user, 'WP_User' ) ) {
        $user_id = $user->ID;

        if( $user ) {
            wp_set_current_user( $user_id, $user->user_login );
            wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_id );
            do_action( 'wp_login', $user->user_login );
        }
        if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

function allow_programmatic_login( $user, $username, $password ) {
    return get_user_by( 'login', $username );
}

function process_login(){

    // this comes from login form
    $username = $_POST["login_username"];

    programmatic_login( $username );

    // it returns true only here, on any other function it returns false
    if(is_user_logged_in()){
        echo "ok";
    }else{
        echo "not ok";
    }

}
```

This is one example where I try to check if user is logged in, outside previous function:

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_login_logout_link', 10, 2);

function add_login_logout_link($items, $args) {

    $loginPage = get_page_by_title("Login");
    $registerPage = get_page_by_title("Register");

    if(is_user_logged_in()){
        $items .= "<li><a href='" . wp_logout_url('index.php') . "' title='Logout'>Logout</a></li>";
    }else{
        $items .= "<li><a href='". site_url() . '/' . '?page_id=' . $loginPage->ID ."'>Login</a></li><li><a a href='". site_url() . '/' . '?page_id=' . $registerPage->ID ."'>Register</a></li>";
    }

    return $items;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest fix is to use wp_login_form()
see reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_login_form
If i understand correctly this should handle everything you want.
This will set the auth cookie and can redirect to the page you want, the login works globally

Comment: That was so easy. Thank you a lot

Answer (score 11):

On codex [wp_set_current_user](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_current_user) there is an example to set the current user and log them in.

```
$user_id = 12345;
$user = get_user_by( 'id', $user_id ); 
if( $user ) {
    wp_set_current_user( $user_id, $user->user_login );
    wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_id );
    do_action( 'wp_login', $user->user_login );
}
```